# Iterate over functons

Tags: python, function, class, python-3.x, graphics

How to iterate over function definitions in a class?

```
class Big:
    def __init__(self):
        self.win = GraphWin("Bounce", 500, 500)
        self.win.setCoords(-10, -10, 10, 10)
        #self.win.getMouse()

    def close(self):
        self.win.getMouse()

    def ball(self):
        x = 1
        y = 1
        #self.win = win
        circ = Circle(Point(x, y), 0.25)
        circ.draw(self.win)

    def move(self):
        movement = [0.5, 0.3]
        x += movement[0]
        y += movement[1]
```

I want to change the values of x and y in the function move. 
How can I do that? Then again create the object Circle

Comment: try making it an attribute of the class.  You probably want to make `x, y` attributes as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python you have to declare private members inside **init** like you do for self.win.

Try adding self.x = 0 in there and access them with self.x everywhere

Comment: I can access these values but I want to edit them in a different function

Comment: The point is that if they are not initialized properly, they become local variables and will be discarded at the end of the function

Comment: if I define whole of the ball function in __init__ , then try to change their values in the move function using (self.x += movement[0]).. this does not work!

Comment: Self.x = 0 in __init__ then self.x+= movement[0] does not work?

Comment: Data attributes can be set in any method, not just .__init__.  But they do have to be set somewhere before being used.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Ball:
   def __init__(self,x,y,rad):
       self.root = root
       self.x = x
       self.y = y
   def draw(self,target):
       Circle(Point(X,y),rad).draw(target)
```

then just use that ..

```
class Big:

    def __init__(self):
        self.win = GraphWin("Bounce", 500, 500)
        self.win.setCoords(-10, -10, 10, 10)
        self.ball = Ball(1,1,0.25)
        #self.win.getMouse()

    def close(self):
        self.win.getMouse()

    def draw(self):
        self.ball.draw(self.win)

    def move(self):
        movement = [0.5, 0.3]
        self.ball.x += movement[0]
        self.ball.y += movement[1]
```

Comment: what does target stands for?